# ATI 6XXX Hybrid Graphics w/open source drivers

Tags: ati, radeon, hybrid

You can turn on/off the dedicated graphics card via OpenSource drivers (acpi_call, vgaswitcheroo, come to mind).  However, there is no way to direct the display to the card.  This card comes with Pavilion dv6.

The proprietary drivers fail to boot Xorg and the Open source drivers return:

```
vga_switcheroo: client 0 refused switch
```

This message indicates that the card can not be switched during X.  Restarting Xorg results in the laptop hanging.  Now that fixed mode is available as indicated below, you can switch on ATI card permanently (for the session) in Windows.

Helpful links:

http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

A BIOS update has been released for the AMD muxless HP dv6/dv7 61xx series.

This is for laptops with a 6470M(?) or 6770M.

The update enables Fixed Mode in the BIOS for discrete-only operation with the Sandy Bridge IGP acting as a mux.

ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp54001-54500/sp54024.exe

Comment: ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp54001-54500/sp54024.html for those running Linux hope you have dual boot!